# I have an avi file on my desktop, but I can't delete it, move it, or modify it

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-corruption, avi

I have a .avi file on my desktop, and I tried to delete it because it was corrupted, as it wouldn't play the video, but only have sound with static noises. I tried to empty the bin, but it just wouldn't do anything, and then I restarted my PC to try again, but I could only restore it. I tried other methods of deleting it after I restored it, but nothing would work. I can't move, modify, or recycle the file anymore. The file size is 2.84 GB, and my OS is Windows 10 if that says anything.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? May seem odd, but without getting into the technicalities, it could help (assuming you haven't done so already)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I have restarted my computer.

Comment: so, you can't restore it now?

Comment: What have you tried, specifically. Do not tell us "I've tried everything" because you haven't, and we do not know what to suggest or not suggest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently the reason why it was so buggy was because the file size was larger than the maximum file size, so I went through some shenanigans to compress it, and that seemed to do the trick. Lol

Answer (score 0):

To repair a broken Recycle Bin, you could do the following :

- Reboot
- Run `chkdsk`
- Test Windows integrity by running the commands
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Set in *Start > File Explorer Options*, View tab, the options of
  "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" and uncheck
  "Hide protected operating system f‌iles"
- Run CMD as Administrator and enter the following command:

  ```
  rd /s /q X:\$Recycle.bin
  ```

  where `X:` is the disk (usually `C:`), then reboot.

Comment: The recycle bin is not broken, the file is. I can recycle, delete, and restore any other file except for the .avi file.

Comment: Nothing changed when I rebooted, I ran the chkdsk command and there seemed to be nothing out of the ordinary, I ran the Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and then sfc /scannow commands and it said that it had repaired the corrupted files, but nothing changed about the avi file.  I don't want to risk unchecking "Hide protected os files" as it said it may make my PC inoperable. And the last method just didn't do anything.

Comment: *uncheck "Hide protected operating system f‌iles"* how is displaying protected OS files supposed to change anything?

Comment: @JaromandaX: It's supposed to make it possible to manually empty the Recycle Bin.

Comment: @joca9: If SFC found errors, I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Take the same precautions as for a major Windows upgrade.

Comment: Update: I restarted my computer and it made really loud beeping noises, almost like an amber alert. I got startled so I unplugged it and plugged it back in and it just acted like I didn't restart in the first place. And just now I got a pop up error with no text and then I couldn't interact with the computer without another restart. I think this file is a big problem.

Comment: I think your computer has bigger problems than the Recycle Bin. I suggest to do the Repair Install before the situation degrades. Afterward you'll need to check the computer for errors.